# Can OpenRefine/google refine be used for pages behind a login?

Tags: web-scraping, openrefine

And if not, is there a comparable alternative that can?

I looked in the documentation but couldn't see anything on this subject, though it must be a common requirement.

And to be clear I mean a web-based login form, not basic HTTP auth.

Answer (score 0):

YES it can be installed behind a proxy for example, a more secure method, since basic auth password is in the clear = bad,
is to install a real web server up-front, use its authentication layer and, say, mod_proxy to tunnel OpenRefine thru.

Here is the simplest example:

```
<VirtualHost __YOUR_IP__:80>

ProxyPass        / http://127.0.0.1:3333/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3333/

<Location />
 AuthType Digest
 AuthName "My Own Hosted Refine"
 AuthUserFile /path/to/my/password.htpasswd
 Require valid-user
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

The ALTERNATIVE, just use an Amazon EC2 instance (or a Cloud hosting provider that offers security groups by IP) that can only be accessed by your IP address - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-application-server.html

Comment: Um, isn't that specifically for http auth... I'm talking about a web form, not http auth.  I did specify that in the question too.

Comment: make whatever web form you need, you can secure it with SSL, etc.  I would suggest that you learn more about mod_proxy and how a web form can be used upfront that can allow a user to login, then be proxied to OpenRefine or whatever other server app you wish.  If you don't have the chops, or do not wish to learn, you can certainly ask someone else to help with the initial setup.

Comment: Updated my answer with an additional Alternative.

Answer (score 0):

@Thad approach is right. I will also take this to point to Tony Hisrt [OpenRefine Docker Containers](http://blog.ouseful.info/2015/01/17/openrefine-docker-containers/).

I don't know if the two are related but I just answered a very similar question on [OpenRefine Mailing List](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/openrefine/WnHkW4NJ4D8).